# Removing a Certain String from an Array in PHP

Tags: php

Hi basically I am trying to remove the current logged in users Id from anywhere in this array

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(4) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" ["user1_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(1) "2" ["user2_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
} 
[1]=> array(4) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" ["user1_id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    [1]=> string(1) "3" ["user2_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 
}
```

This is my array and what I need to do is remove the current users ID for arguments sake this can be 1.

Comment: Don't you think it's easier to do in the query itself?

Comment: So what's the expected output in this case?

Comment: My end goal is for it to simply return a array without the current users ID so in this case I would want it to return 2 and 3

Comment: And you haven't tried doing that with a simple `foreach`? Btw, you should consider to change the fetch style to "assoc" instead of "array".

Comment: Yes but that is not what I am confused about. I am uncertain how to remove just that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a database problem rather than an array problem.

```
SELECT IF(`user1_id` = 1, `user2_id`, `user1_id`) AS `user`
FROM mytable
WHERE user1_id = 1 OR user2_id = 1
```

Comment: is there a way that If user1_id = 1 then select user2_id and vice versa

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this, Sorry I am new to php as you have probably realised

Comment: Hey this only would get the 2 and not the 3 do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @cool37132 Why don't you write a sqlfiddle so that I can see what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: The weirdest thing just happened I put it into sql fiddle and it worked fine so I am now officially confused